# Accessing A CultureInfo setting (locale)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

If I set a user's culture info in Global.asax such that strCulture is the locale "en-US":

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(strCulture);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
    = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(strCulture);
```

then how do I access the culture i set elsewhere in the application (after login)?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear when you're setting it nor what you mean by "elsewhere". I presume there's some reason that it isn't the obvious answer of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent much consideration before posting this as well, but as Peter mentioned earlier in the comment I can't really come up with a better way then using `CurrentUICulture`.

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

If that's not what you are looking for, please give us more information. :)